# Oracle | Varchar2 | Number Equality | Different output

Tags: sql, oracle, select, varchar2

I have a table in Oracle, let's say `Table1`:

```
Column - ticketNo - NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
```

Now when I run different queries, I get different outputs, though record is present.

```
select * 
from Table1 
where ticketNo = '0900000106'; -- Fetches the record

select * 
from Table1 
where ticketNo = '0810087720'; -- Fetches the record

select * 
from Table1 
where ticketNo = '0050001104'; -- Fetches the record

select * 
from Table1 
where ticketNo = '3180000013'; -- Fetches the record


select * 
from Table1 
where ticketNo = '900000100'; --  Does not fetch the record

select * 
from Table1 
where ticketNo = '5889770';    -- Fetches the record

select * 
from Table1 
where ticketNo = 0900000106; -- Fetches the record

select * from Table1 where ticketNo = 0810087720; -- Fetches the record
select * from Table1 where ticketNo = 0050001104; -- Fetches the record
select * from Table1 where ticketNo = 3180000013; -- Fetches the record

select * from Table1 where ticketNo = 900000100; --  Fetches the record
select * from Table1 where ticketNo = 5889770;    -- Fetches the record
```

I am not able to understand why for the few records '' comparison fails.

I am using SQL Developer to query above.

Oracle IDE  17.4.1.054.0712

Comment: So what's the actual value? `'0900000106'` or `'900000106'`? Seems clear it has to do with `INT` conversion

Comment: @HoneyBadger actual value is 0900000100

Comment: Also, if the column is a string, the version with quotes is correct. Whether it gets a row or not.

Comment: Well then it is clear isn't it? `900000106 = 900000106` is true, `'0900000100' = '900000100'` is not

Comment: Don't compare numbers and strings. As ticketno is a varchar, you should only compare it to varchar values. Never rely on implicit data type conversion

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes got your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[When comparing a character value with a numeric value, Oracle converts the character data to a numeric value](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm#:%7E:text=Implicit%20Data%20Conversion,in%20which%20it%20is%20made.)

For example when your compare `ticketNo = 900000106` the character value '0900000106' of ticketNo is converted to number 900000106 and matches the right term of equality.